# In JavaScript, when use .map() function to iterate array with primitive types and with object

Tags: javascript, arrays

If the array is `[true, false]`, and use `.map()` to iterate it, the array itself is not changed

```
array.map(item => {
   item = false
})
```

array is still `[true, false]`

But if the items of array are object, then the array would be changed
Initially, array is `[{checked: true}, {checked: false}]`,
and iterate over the map,

```
array.map(item => {
    item.checked = false
})
```

then array becomes  `[{checked: false}, {checked: false}]`

can anyone tell me what the difference is between the two?

Comment: read [Array#map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ... .map returns a new array, mapped to the values returned from the callback - you are currently using `Array#map` like you would use `Array#forEach` - though, you probably are excused from doing so, some time ago people would do that because Chrome map was significantly faster than forEach (at least it was in the past)

Comment: When an object is passed as an argument to a function, the value passed is a **reference** to the object, not a complete copy of the object. When a *primitive* is passed, however, it *is* a copy that's passed. Setting the value of the parameter to something different in that case has no effect, but using the object reference to access the object does allow you to modify the object; that's just how object references work.

Comment: I think this is the use case of [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) not [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)! Plus as @Pointy pointed out: objects are passed by reference, if you change that reference the original object will be changed as well!

Comment: Technically, JavaScript is [*always* pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), but the value passed for an object is a "reference" (or pointer) to the object.

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to use .forEach() instead of .map() in the first example, but the array keeps intact. why? thanks

Comment: Because you aren't updating the array item value

Comment: @JaromandaX 
let array = [true, false]
array.forEach(item => {item = false}]
array is the same

Comment: yes, because you are updating `item`, which is a local (to the function) "variable" ... `array.forEach((item, index, array) => {array[index] = false})` will do what you expect

Comment: technically, you can remove the `{}` ... `array.forEach((item, index, array) => array[index] = false);` ... see arrow function documentation for explanation

Comment: @JaromandaX Excellent. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: JavaScript functions receive **variables passed by value, but objects passed by reference.**

In your first example, `item` inside the function body is simply a new reference created on the spot that contains the value of whatever is passed as the `item` parameter. This means you can do whatever you want with it, the variable outside the function body will not change unless you explicitly set it.

In your second example however, the `item` inside the function body is a reference to the actual object outside the function passed as parameter. This means that any changes you make to it inside the function will also change the external object referenced by `item`.

A more thorough explanation on passing variables by value vs by reference can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/5120832).

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are not the correct usage for `.map()`. `map()` returns a new array based on iterating the original one (which it does not alter). You get elements into that new array by returning them and then capturing the overall return value from `map()`.

```
var newArray = array.map(item => {
    return item === false;
});
```

The only reason you falsely believed that using objects made `.map()` work differently is because you were modifying the object's property values, which are stored within the object, but not the array directly.

In your case, you just need to be iterating the array, so you should be using `.forEach()`.

Comment: will .forEach() create a new array but the original array keeps intact? or will it modify the content of array?

Comment: .forEach returns `undefined` ... always ... it will do what you tell it to do in the callback, but modifying the "item" (first argument) will have no effect - modifying a PROPERTY of item will change the property of the item in the original array

Answer (score 0):

`Array#map` doesn't do what you think it does. It loops through the array and calls the function you passed with each value, and a new array is created with the return values.

For example:

```js
function doAction(str) {
  try {
    const array = JSON.parse(str);
    return JSON.stringify(
      // Pay attention to this line:
      array.map(item => item + 1)
    );
  } catch (e) {
    return 'Error: ' + e;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Input an array of numbers then press "Map it!" to double each of them.</p>
<input id="arrayIn" />
<button onclick="arrayOut.value = doAction(arrayIn.value)">Map it!</button>
<input id="arrayOut" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### .map() returns a new array explanation:

This means that `var array` is not mutated (or changed at all by map,  by a new array is created to hold the mapped values and returned.

Consider this:

```
var array = [true, false];
var newArray = array.map(item => {
   return item = false;
});
console.log(array);    // logs out [true, false]
console.log(newArray); // logs out [false, false]
```

> In short, it works but you need to use the ***value returned*** by
>   **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

---

Comment: did you check your code? `newArray` == `[undefined, undefined]`

Comment: to return what you claim, you would do `var newArray = array.map(() => false);`

Comment: @JaromandaX: nice catch, forgot my `return` statement within `.map()` even though I mentioned it in the closing sentence :P.  Amended it accordingly.

Comment: you don't even need the `item =` part either :p

Comment: @JaromandaX: technically could use an empty braced arrow and implicit false (`array.map(() => false)`, but didn't want to create too much of a leap from the OP's original code.